# Is there a way to generate serverless.yml from existent aws environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I already have a dev environment set up and want to replicate it for production. But for that I would have to generate a whole new serverless.yml file. Is there a way to generate it automatically?

Comment: I'm assuming that you built your dev environment by hand, not using serverless. Not aware of any way to do this and, tbh, most 'infrastructure to template' solutions (like CloudFormer) are far from ideal. I'd just move forward and build from scratch.

Comment: Are you refering to the serverless framework https://www.serverless.com/?

Comment: Yes I am, Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

serverless.yml is converted to cloudformation which is understandable by AWS.

I believe you could do it with your existing serverless.yml

Please have a look at:

- https://www.serverless.com/blog/stages-and-environments
- https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/stages-in-serverless-framework.html
- https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/workflow#using-stages